Injective MPS and unique ground state
I am learning tensor network (e.g., MPS (matrix product state) and PEPS (projected entangled pair state)), via the RMP of I. Cirac, el al, and the lecture note by J. Bridgeman et al. However, I do not understand the connection between, injective MPS, and a unique eigenvalue of the transfer matrix with eigenvalues of norm 1, e.g., Sec. IV. A in 1 and Sec. 4.2 in 2.
It would be great if you can help me understand this, like how to derive this result.
